# Recover all incoming message from the websocket of an android app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, websocket, reverse-engineering

I'd like to recover the message sent from the websocket of an android app.

I already found the websocket adress and I can connect to it but I don't receive any messages.

```
import json
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection('wss://XXX.firebaseio.com/')

while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    result = json.loads(result)
    print ("Received '%s'" % result)
ws.close()
```

Here's the code I used, I suppose firebase is using some sort of protection but I really don't know what kind. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://www.wireshark.org/ ...while the connection might not do a thing by itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, the problem is that the application is using cert pinning so wireshark will be kind of useless here :/

Comment: there is a way to get the connection logs in plain text (in case they did not go the extra mile to beef up security measures)... possibly voiding terms of service (won't tell).

Comment: And those connection logs will allow me to listen every message received on this websocket ?